# VR: Put item in hand from List

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-engine, virtual-reality

I hope you are doing well.

So I am creating a VR with XR game in which I have a list of items as Scriptable Objects. Now I want to put one item in my hand when I press a button but I run into problems because my function is not doing the right thing. This is how it looks like:

```
public void PutItemInHand()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < inventoryItems.Count; i++)
    {
        if (inventoryItems[i].name == "Sword")
        {
            Instantiate(inventoryItems[i], handSpawn.position, handSpawn.rotation);
        }
        else if (inventoryItems[i].name == "Gun")
        {
            Instantiate(inventoryItems[i], handSpawn.position, handSpawn.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

Also it says: "Cannot instantiate a ScriptableObject with a position and rotation".

Do you guys have an idea? I would be grateful for any help.
Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

It is right, you can not instantiate a scriptable object with a position or rotation, simply because ScriptableObjects don't have components nor Transforms.

what you want to do is instantiate a prefab of your item, so you can do something like `Instantiate(inventoryItems[i].itemPrefab, handSpawn.position, handSpawn.rotation);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

So I can "delete" my scriptable object and use a prefab instead?

The problem of the function is that both items are in the list and my loop would go into both if-cases and I don't know how to do it properly. In the beginning I have no item in my hand and by pressing a button the UI of the inventory pops up and by clicking on the button of the item I want to have it in my hand.

Also, I need to put it back into the inventory and in another case replace it with the other item. I don't know how to do it to be honest :D

Comment: you can add a `GameObject` variable to your scriptable object to reference your prefab.

And for your loop problem you can add a `break;` instruction after each `Instantiate` to exit the loop after instantiating the item.

Comment: Well, I don't have a prefab of it :D How can I connect the the prefab and the GameObject?
How would the loop look like then? Like imagine that I have the UI of my inventory and I press the button for the gun.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand... when you click the sword for example, you want a sword to appear, so you have to create a sword in the scene in the first place, and then you can turn it into a prefab to use with your scriptable

Comment: Prefabs helped out, it works now :D
Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear, don't forget to accept the answer :)